# How can I generate commerce file audio preview automatically?

Tags: entities, commerce, files

In a store of music files with the [Commerce File](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_file) module, how can I generate an audio preview of that file? Would be perfect if I could use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module for detect the adding of file and [SOX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) utility for audio trim (for example the first 20 seconds) and attach the generated file into another field.

If possibile compatible with [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) and [SoundManager2](http://drupal.org/project/soundmanager2).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an awesome companion module that could be created and would be popular. From a bit of Googling, you can use SOX or FFMPEG-PHP and the exec() command to actually trim the audio file. From there, it's just a matter of saving this audio file to a new field. I would not use rules unless you need to expose it in the interface for some reason. You could easily achieve the programmatic saving of an audio field (probably a specialized file field) using any of a number of examples out there on the web.

Found an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884960/ffmpeg-php-code-example-to-trim-mp3-file

```
<?php
exec('$ sox input.wav output.wav trim 0 10');
?>
```